Cannot update state from child element in React (functional components)
I want to have a child component reference and update a state; however, when I try to do so, it only works once or twice before breaking. Strangely, the parent element can still update the state.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function RegistrationPopup() {
  const [advancedMode, setAdvancedMode] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(null);

  // The child function that tries to call setAdvancedMode
  const child = (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode);
        }}
      >
        set advanced mode child
      </button>
    </div>
  );

  // Set the current page to the child
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPage(child);
  }, []);

  // Return the parent component, which references the child
  return (
    <div>
      {"mode is: " + (advancedMode ? "advanced" : "normal")}
      <br />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode);
        }}
      >
        set advanced mode parent
      </button>

      {currentPage}
    </div>
  );
}

Even though the parent and child elements both call setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode), only the parent element actually updates the state. The child element will not trigger a state change, as shown in this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/holy-monad-wlw4gq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

You are essentially memoizing your child via the useEffect and because of the closure that it is memoized in advancedMode in setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode); is always the inital value of false. This means everytime you click the button in the child you are just setting advanceMode to true. You can see this in your provided sandbox by using the parent button to set it to "Normal" and then the child button can be used to set it back to "Advanced". Either don't memoize the child or use setAdvancedMode(current => !current); in it's onClick.

Don't store JSX in React state, store only data, and render the JSX from state. React UI is a function of state and props.

As @drew-reese points out, it's bad practice to store JSX states in react states. However, if you have to make it work (from @jacob-smitt's comment), you can change setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode) to setAdvancedMode(current => !current).

Separate out your child component and pass setAdvancedMode as props
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sad-sanderson-7rk34k?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A2%2C1
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ChildComponent = ({ advancedMode, setAdvancedMode }) => (
  <div>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode);
      }}
    >
      set advanced mode child
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default function RegistrationPopup() {
  const [advancedMode, setAdvancedMode] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPage(
      <ChildComponent advancedMode={advancedMode} setAdvancedMode={setAdvancedMode} />
    );
  }, [advancedMode]); // Re-create the child component when advancedMode changes

  return (
    <div>
      {"mode is: " + (advancedMode ? "advanced" : "normal")}
      <br />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setAdvancedMode(!advancedMode);
        }}
      >
        set advanced mode parent
      </button>

      {currentPage}
    </div>
  );
}
``

